# Linear Operator identity prrof

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let A,B be invertible linear operators. Prove the identity: $B^{-1}-A^{-1}=B^{-1}(A-B)A^{-1}$

Comment: Multiply with $B$ from the left and $A$ from the right

Comment: expand the right side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Multiply  this equality on the right by $A$ and on the left by $B$.